# SQL. I'm stuck with this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

`select SUM(category)
from film_list
where title IN actors;`

I'm stuck, I'm working on the sakila database and I'm trying to figure out  film categories in which there are between 55 and 65 films. Return the names of these
categories and the number of films per category, sorted by the number of films.Pls any ideas?

Comment: You're so far from your destination that it seems futile to assist. See a good book or tutorial on MySQL, then get back to us.

Comment: Please provide an outline schema (a more or less minimal one) and some sample data, and the expected output from that data.  Clearly, 55 or more rows is too many for a question here; you could decide to use 'between 5 and 6' or some similar smaller range — it would make it easier to provide a few rows of sample data.  I think there'd be perhaps 2 or 3 columns of data needed (one would be category; title and one other might be appropriate).

Comment: It's the [Sakila sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/). It's available in [MySQL's website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) under Example Databases.

Comment: @Revenant: Useful information — but it should have been in the question.  Sure, I could probably find it quickly with Google, but people shouldn't have to search to work out what the question means.  And the question should be self-contained; it can have the link to complete the details, but it should still outline the schema of the table(s) considered relevant, and some sample data and the expected output are reasonable pre-requisites.  A discussion of the output of the SQL would be good too — in this case, it would be a syntax error, as far as I can see.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The asker did _mention_ it, but I agree. One can't really be bothered to import a whole schema of 30+ tables and views for a query that only uses one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT category, Count(*) AS FilmsCount
FROM Film_List
GROUP BY Category
HAVING Count(*) BETWEEN 55 AND 65
ORDER BY FilmsCount
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a group by and having

```
select category, count(*) as num_film
from film_list
group by category 
having num_film BETWEEN 55 AND 65
order by num_fim
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it answers this query: 
- Find all the film categories in which there are between 55 and 65 films. Return the names of these
categories and the number of films per category, sorted by the number of films.

```
SELECT 
    category.name,
    COUNT(fc.category_id) AS `Movies per Category`
FROM
    film_category AS fc
        JOIN
category ON fc.category_id = category.category_id
GROUP BY fc.category_id
HAVING `Movies per Category` BETWEEN 65 AND 75
ORDER BY `Movies per Category` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS films_per_category
  FROM film_list
 GROUP BY category
HAVING COUNT(*) BETWEEN 55 AND 65
 ORDER BY films_per_category
```

But there wouldn't be so much guessing if you'd provided an outline schema and some sample data.  Granted, we'd not want to see 55 rows, but for demo purposes, between 5 and 6 rows would work OK.

Answer (score 0):

This is called subquery:

```
select sum(category)
from film_list
where title IN (SELECT title FROM actors);
```

Comment: Please discuss your reasoning — why are you summing categories, why does the actors table contain a title column, where is the category name, where is the condition on 55-65 rows, etc.

Comment: While the info is missing, i thought to give an example of how to write a sub-query. Don't be so hard on me.